# angular with webApi - Models first letter should be uppercase or lowercase

Tags: angular, typescript

very much new to angular and facing this issue where my result from Webapi model's first letter is upper-case even though my angular model's first letter is lower-case.

## User.ts

```
    export interface User extends ICommon {
        id: string;
        firstName: string;
        lastName: string;
    }
```

## User.service.ts

```
     public getActiveUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
      return this.http
       .get<User[]>(baseUrl + "user/GetUserlist");
```

}

Console. output shows:

[image]

## User.component.html

```
    {{user.firstName}}  => shows no result
    {{user.FirstName}}  => shows proper result
```

## User.component.ts

```
    let result = this.user.firstName => undefined
    let result = this.user.FirstName => compile time error.
```

what am i doing wrong here? i am confused.

Comment: Please post your component code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the server uses PascalCasing, and you defined an interface which does not match the data returned by a server.

Change your interface as

```
export interface User extends ICommon {
        Id: string;
        FirstName: string;
        LastName: string;
}
```

and access as

```
let result = this.user.FirstName
```

If your backend is WebApi, by default the normal Json serialization leaves the fields as they are in you c# casing.

Comment: let me try and see

Comment: perfect.. this is working fine now. Also in other places where other models are used , it's working with lowercase as well the data is being returned through WebApi and no special serialization setting has been used.  Anyway, i think that's out of the scope for this question. appreciate your help and time.